# kapranov's realization of $\overline{M}_{0,n}$ over other fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, blow-ups, moduli-spaces, tag-removed, algebraic-curves

Kapranov gave a very nice desciption, over $\mathbb{C}$ of the moduli space of stable pointed rational curves $\overline{M}_{0,n}$ as a series of blow-ups of $P^{n-3}$. Does this, or a similar result, hold over other fields? e.g. positive characteristic, non algebraically closed, etc.

ps
I am afraid one could only dream of this, over non alg closed fields...

Comment: what is the reference for Kapranov's result ?


Comment: The paper is called "chow quotients of grassmannians 1".

Comment: @Alexander: there are also other realizations as a blow up, see Keel, Intersection theory of moduli spaces of stable n-pointed curves of genus 0.



Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to me Kapranov's methods are purely algebraic and that his description works verbatim over $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbf Z)$.

Comment: @Dan: thank you for answering, I have checked the paper and in fact it does seem that you are right. So probably he works over $\mathbb{C}$ just for sake of simplicity?